# CVE-2021-24112, CVE-2021-26701 showing severity score as 9.8 on Restsharp upgrade

Tags: c#, nuget-package, restsharp, .net-4.7.2, cve

I upgraded the restSharp from 106.13.0 to 108.0.2 on .Net Framework 4.7.2 and, since then, I'm getting both CVE-2021-24112, CVE-2021-26701 Severity as CRITICAL with score of 9.8 on Dependency Scan Results (dotnet)

I also observed Fixed version as 6.0.8 on 'System.Text.Encoding' in Dependency Scan Results (dotnet), but could not able to find 6.0.8 on 'System.Text.Encodings.Web' nuget package.

**Actual Dependency Scan Results:**

Id               │ Package              │ Version        │ Fix Version │ Severity │ Score

CVE-2021-24112 │ System.Text.Encoding │ >=5.0-<=5.0.2  │ 6.0.8       │ CRITICAL │   9.8

CVE-2021-26701 │ System.Text.Encoding │ >=5.0-<5.0.4   │ 6.0.8       │ CRITICAL │   9.8

**What I tried:**
I tried to update the latest restSharp (108.0.2) and System.Text.Encodings.Web (6.0.0) nuget packages but the issue still persist.

**What I need:**
The severity score should be reduced for CVE-2021-24112, CVE-2021-26701 on dependency scan results.

Did I missing anything here?

Any insights could be really helpful.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are not gonna "reduce a CVE severity". If it is present it will score whatever it was cataloged at... And CVE-2021-24112 is a remote code execution one so it is gonna score high. Do you notice that `System.Text.Encoding` is different to `System.Text.Encodings.Web`? Upgrade the correct package

Comment: The reason to update 'System.Text.Encodings.Web' is I am unable to find the 'System.Text.Encoding' package in the project and found many references points to update 'System.Text.Encodings.Web' to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade `System.Text.Json` to the latest version in your project, as `System.Text.Encoding` is one of its dependencies. The lowest version constraint of RestSharp is 5.0.1, and you can install any version you want above that.